# IIS Load Balancing and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing

Basically, I have 3 servers where 1 of them serves as a load balancing server.

In my ASPX page, I want to add a HTML comment to show the IP address or even host name of the server selected by the load balancer.

I tried looking through [IIS Server variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28VS.90%29.aspx) and tried using **SERVER_NAME** but that just returns the domain URL.

So, is there any way to do this programming in ASP.NET?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about System.Environment.MachineName

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the host name, filter/map the host name and output it as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

For IP address:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].ToString();
```

For local server hostname:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

**EDIT:**

@Conrad's answer above (`System.Environment.MachineName`) also works for the host name.

Comment: Note that the first approach is not reliable (like any other HttpRequest based solution as well). It may return "::1" if the user opened the page from localhost.